# Can a land possessor distrain a trespasser's property?

Tags: criminal-law, property, trespass

*A* has entered *B*'s land for lawful purposes. *B* commands *A* to leave, but *B* parks his ATV behind *A*'s vehicle, obstructing its only avenue of backing out to drive away (there are three other cars parked next to *A*'s vehicle). *A* refuses to leave the land without his vehicle.

Would *A*'s refusal to leave without his vehicle still expose him to a criminal trespass charge?

Edit for the two commenters: 1. it was a clip I saw from Minnesota that prompted the question. 2. The ATV already belongs to land possessor *B*. The question is whether *A* can lawfully refuse to leave *B*'s land when *B* boxes in *A*'s car so that *A* cannot leave the property unless the car is left there.

Comment: In which jurisdiction?

Comment: The question body asks a different question than the topic line. Are you asking if B is within their rights to seize the ATV, or are you asking whether A is within their rights to refuse to leave under those circumstances?